# Must skolem functions depend on unused variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

When converting formulas to CNF, we replace existentially quantified variables with Skolem functions that depend on surrounding universally quantified variables. For example, in

∀x ∃y p(x,y)

the value of `y` depends on the particular `x`, so `y` will be replaced by `f(x)`.

What if the universally quantified variable was unused in the existentially quantified formula, i.e. is not a free variable in the body of the existential quantifier?

∀x ∃y p(y)

Can we simplify matters by ignoring `x` completely and just replacing `y` with a Skolem *constant* `a`?

Comment: Yes, we can. $\forall x A$ is equivalent to $A$ if there is **no** free occurrences of $x$ in $A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically yes, but as sticklers for details we shouldn't *literally* refer to $p({\bf a})$ as the Skolemization of $\forall x\exists y(p(y))$.  Rather, we should say that $\forall x\exists y(p(y))$ is **equivalent to** $\exists y(p(y))$, and the Skolemization of the *latter* is $p({\bf a})$ for a fresh constant symbol ${\bf a}$.

This is a bit hair-splitting, but it is the technically accurate way to do things; in particular, there is a serious difference between adding a *unary function symbol* versus a *constant (= nullary function) symbol* to a language.